# Does BEGIN TRANSACTION do any sort of row/column locking?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I use begin transaction in my stored procedure.  I have code that updates data:

```
UPDATE
     employee
SET
     name = @name,
     surname = @surname
WHERE
     empId = @empid;
```

Does SQL Server do any locking on the row or coloumn that is being updated?  If this is not the case, how would I prevent other users from doing another update while there is a current update in progress?  It doeesn't have to be in the stored procedure, C# is also an option.

Comment: No - BEGIN TRANSACTION alone doesn't do anything. The `UPDATE` statement will try to acquire **update locks** (U) on the row (or rows) being updated, and hold on to those locks until the transaction completes (with a `COMMIT` or a `ROLLBACK`).

Comment: @marc_s: This is not 100% accurate. **(1)** Usually, the `U` lock is taken when the row is read. Then, when `SQL Server` decides to update the it takes a `X` lock by converting the `U` lock to `X` lock on row. **(2)** But, in some cases, `SQL Server` decides to take directly an `X` lock (so, no `U` lock and then `U -> X` conversion).

Comment: @BogdanSahlean: OK - maybe - but the `BEGIN TRANSACTION` on its own doesn't do anything - that's really what the OP was asking. RIght??

Comment: @marc_s: Strictly, yes. But an explicit transaction (`BEGIN TRAN ... `) + another transaction isolation level (ex. `SERIALIZABLE`) can change the duration of life for `U` locks till the end of transaction  (`COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`). Maybe this aspect is important for OP (it's just a supposition).

Comment: @BrendanVogt: OP = original poster - in this case: **YOU!** :-)

Comment: @BrendanVogt: What it means "update in progress" ? One user open a Windows/Web form and changes some data and, in the same time, another user tries and succeeds to update the same information ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server does issue locks against the objects being accessed - and locking gets pretty complex in terms of what is happening under the covers.

For your specific update statement, assuming a single row is being updated.

- Row : Update Lock to gain access to Update the data which then converts to an Exclusive Lock when the data is modified.
- Page : Intent Update, which converts to an Intent Exclusive when the data is modified.
- Table : Intent Update.

There are a lot of details about the locking modes on the MS site : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175519(v=sql.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

By default MSSQL creates a row level lock for the UPDATE statement. All the rows which will be affected by the UPDATE statement would be locked so that no other user would be able to modify those rows while the update is taking place.

You can modify the default locking behavior by making use of Locking Hints: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213026%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

if this is the only statement in the sproc, then it is a transaction. Remember each statement is atomic and either works or doesn't, you don't need to worry about locking.